# How do use Bundling & Minification from another server JQuery files

Tags: c#

I want to use bundling and minification of my jquery files in asp.net with C#
for this purpose I have use following way.

Hide   Copy Code

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/JS/JqueryNode").Include(
                             "~/Scripts/Common/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.js"
                             "~/Scripts/Common/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"
                             "~/JS/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js",
                             "~/Scripts/Chat/jquery.extensions.js",
                             "~/Scripts/Chat/jquery.cssemoticons.js"
                           ));
```

But my issue that I want all these file should bind from another server or remote server, for this purpose i have use cdn path in following line

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/JS/JqueryNode", cdnPath).include
```

But problem is that cdn path accept a single file, and i want all these files should bind from that remote server.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to bundle and minify files from a content delivery network with your own scripts before serving them from your own server?

Comment: I just want bundle and minify files from content delivery network not from local. content delivery network is another network  hosted as library of jquery and css files

Comment: why are you using a CDN? Downloading the file from CDN, bundle, minify, sent to user would make you spend a lot of data transfer, you also could lose the global load balance and speed.

Comment: requiremnet as such that we want all js, css and images on cdn and call on application

Comment: Did you explore IncludeDirectory options instead of Include? For example, bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/customjs").IncludeDirectory(
                "~/Scripts/Custom","*.js");

Comment: Cdn parameter only accept file not directory path either use include or includedirectory, where can collect all files from directory.